# Function which calculates the mean

Tags: r, function, mean

I have a problem with my function. I must create the function which return the values greater than mean. For example I have vector (3,6,3,12,4). Mean = 5,6 , so the function should return the values : 6,12. I try create this function but I lost. How I can fix this problem?

````
  for(i in 1:length(u))
  { 
    if(u[i] > mean(u))
      return(u[i])
    return()
  }
}

u <- c(3,6,3,12,4)
is.mean(u) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily without any loop

```
is.mean <- function(u) u[u>mean(u)]
is.mean(u)
#[1]  6 12
```

EDIT: Based on comments from @Abdessabour Mtk

---

Or using a `for` loop, create a `NULL` vector ('u1'), loop over the values of 'u', `if` the condition i.e. the value is greater than `mean` of the `vector` append the 'val' with the vector 'u1' and update by assigning (`<-`) to that vector

```
is.mean <- function(u) {
  u1 <- c()
  for(val in u) {
    if(val > mean(u)) u1 <- c(u1, val)
    }

 u1
 }

is.mean(u)
#[1]  6 12
```

#### data

```
u <- c(3,6,3,12,4)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have an exercise and I must create the function

Comment: maybe OP wants the first code wrapped in a function

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk it is already wrapped in a function.  I meant the `is.mean` for `for` loop

Comment: your first answer. `is.mean <- function(u) u[u>mean(u)]`